# Trying to use XML in Google Sheets to get data from last instance of a class

Tags: xml, google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula, formula

Apologies if this is formatted poorly; I've never had to ask a question here before. Usually Stack Overflow has the answer!

Anyway, I need a spreadsheet that tracks the comments in a threaded discussion. Specifically, I need it to give me the username of the **last person** who commented on the thread.

Here is the spreadsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VwVo1l2r2IVBPUcHO3NlxIXnoeM2xkviIct_pjvjBlg/edit?usp=sharing

I was thinking there must be a way to add a 'last child' modifier to the class, but so far I haven't found a way to input that into the formula so it would work. If you click the link in the spreadsheet, you'll see that for the formula in C2 to work like I need it to, the answer *should* be **a1b2**.

I need the formula to update automatically, to track the progress of comment threads, so using `id="comment-cmt933"` would not work, since the numbers assigned to individual comments are random; using that id would just statically track that comment, and not update when a further comment was added to the thread.

Is what I'm trying to do possible with google sheets / XML / the markup of this website? I've looked everywhere and was unable to find an answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the HTML I can see that all posters have their username been captured in b-nodes in synchronized order. Therefor I tried the following:

```
=IMPORTXML(B2,"//b[count(following::b)=0]")
```

I was more keen on using `=IMPORTXML(B2,"//b[last()]")`, however somehow GS keeps returning all b-nodes instead of the last one. Not sure if this is GS-specific (or the XPath can be better written?), but in Excel it would have worked fine.

Comment: Thank you, this is still very helpful if I ever have to migrate this to an excel file, which is a distinct possibility. I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: @johnnydangerously, you are welcome. If it has answered the question consider to mark the answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of it and therefor close the thread.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML(B2, "//b"), COUNTA(IMPORTXML(B2, "//b")))
```

[image]